# Usage of Node js calling socket.io functions

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

In my nodeClient.js, i am having one function

```
socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );
```

and

```
socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

$( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

it is clearly visible here that, the socket.on() function is using here to push the data into that particular id,

but, if I check the id in the html

```
<ul id="messages">
    <?php 
        $query = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY msgid DESC' );
        $query->execute();

        $messages = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        foreach( $messages as $message ):
    ?>
            <li> <strong><?php echo $message->name; ?></strong> : <?php echo $message->message; ?> </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

in the html page, we are fetching the data from the database using mysql query, this is working fine with php without node js also... 
Now, my question is "How the socket.on() or socket.emit() functions are helping out to get the result."

This is my complete nodeClient.js file

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();
//alert(msg);
socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

// Ajax call for saving datas
$.ajax({
url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
type: "POST",
data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
success: function(data) {

}
});

return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

$( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

and this is my nodeServer.js

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );

    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

        client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    });
});

server.listen( 8080 );
```

Anyone please  help me for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone, please ask me if they need information more clearly, I will provide.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem. As far as I can see your code works.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Krasimir, as long as you are emitting from the node server to the client who is receiving the `emit()` from the server, your code should be working fine.

Comment: Yes, my code is working properly. But, I dont feel any difference in the output with and without node js. Can you please explain me what node js is doing here...

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs updates the content of your div real time. You don't have to load the page. If you use only php you need to refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: You said that "the content will update automatically without refreshing the page". But, it is not happening here. The content is not updating in the page until I refresh the page. That's because I asked this question

Comment: There is a nodejs server which should be send a message via the socket to the client. Is that happening? Can you please post the code of the nodejs script.

Comment: I just append my nodeClient.js and nodeServer.js files in the question, please check and let me know.

Comment: I should ask how you actually test. As far as I can see you are running everything on local host. You should open several tabs into your browser and try sending messages. The code looks ok. I'll suggest to check the console where you run the nodejs part and the console of the browser to see if there are any errors. Also you are sending a message to the clients twice. You could remove *io.sockets.emit* or *client.broadcast.emit*. The second one send message to every socket except the one which stands behind *client*.

Comment: I opened in multiple tabs and checked. The message will appear on the browser only after refreshing the page. I commented the //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } ); . still facing this and I did'nt see any error in console too.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of the console which you use to start the nodejs server. Of course make some form submissions.

Comment: What you mean nothing. There should be at least *New client !*. Do you actually run the app via *node nodeServer.js*.